# I need help arranging different values using vba code

Tags: vba, excel

So I have an excel sheet that has information that a user can put to look at different times. The problem I have is that I want the user to pick on cell c7 if they want to use the server or grid, depending on their answer they will get different responses on the cell (c9). In the code, I am having a problem that it doesn't know if the user picks grid or server. So I would like to add that to my code. Here is my code.

```
Sub findData()
Dim workflow As String
Dim server As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

workflow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c5").Value
server = Sheets("sheet1").Range("c9").Value
Grid = Sheets("sheet1").Range("c9").Value

finalrow = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("c100").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 5 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 3) = workflow Then
    If Cells(i, 4) = server Then
    If Cells(i, 5) = Grid Then
    Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 12)).Copy
    Range("j42").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    End If
    End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not this approach instead?

```
Sub findData()
Dim workflow As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

workflow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c5").Value

finalrow = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("c100").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 5 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 3) = workflow Then ' 1. If Cells(i, 3) = workflow
    If Cells(i, 4) = "Server" Then ' 2. If Cells(i, 4) = "Server"
    Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 12)).Copy
    Range("j42").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    ElseIf Cells(i, 4) = "Grid" Then ' 2. If Cells(i, 4) = "Server"
    Else ' 2. If Cells(i, 4) = "Server"
    'not handled
    End If ' 2. If Cells(i, 4) = "Server"
    End If ' 1. If Cells(i, 3) = workflow
Next i

End Sub
```